# OpenCV KeyPoint: information about angle and octave

Tags: opencv

I want to know more about KeyPoints, so can anyone told me what are

---

#### KeyPoint::angle

In OpenCV docs was mentioned that angle is computed orientation of the keypoint (-1 if not applicable). I can not imagine that what it is about. So Can anyone say me what it means or bring a small example.

---

#### KeyPoint::octave

In OpenCV docs was mentioned that octave is octave (pyramid layer) from which the keypoint has been extracted. I can not imagine that what it is about. So Can anyone say me what it means or bring a small example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to understand the basics, just go to the basics:

http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf

It is the first, and one of the most influential papers about image feature description/extraction. You may find it a bit hard to swallow, but it offers a good explanation of a complex problem.

Comment: While this paper deals with SIFT, it should be noted that OpenCV offers other feature detection algorithms like SURF which return these KeyPoints as well. The concepts are still the same.

Answer (score 5):

If someone doesn't want to read the paper by Lowe, which @sammy mentioned, here is some short resume:

- **Image pyramid** (see [OpenCV doc](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/pyramids/pyramids.html) and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_%28image_processing%29)) is basically a set of images based on a single image that we have downsampled and downscaled multiple times. An example for such pyramid is the Gaussian pyramid. We use pyramids in feature detection and matching for various reasons. It has been noticed in the past that downsampling and also downscaling an image to a certain level does not mean that we loose all the features that we require for feature matching for example and in fact it often removes some of the noise. High resolution (not to be confused with the image's width and height!) is also often not something that we need since (wikipedia) higher resolution also means more details in the image but more details also means more processing power required, which is a killer if you run your application on a platform with low performance and low power consumption in mind such as smartphones. If you combine this with a huge scale of your image (dimensions) the whole thing gets even worse. Of course it depends on the image and on the number of layers our pyramid has. As we know downsampling alters the pixels in the image in a way. Each feature is described by a keypoint and a descriptor. Because of the change in pixels when downsampling features also change and so do their descriptors and keypoints. That is why a keypoint has to store the information at which level in the image pyramid it was extracted. Note that creating image pyramids requires a decent amount of resources. However this trade-off is justified when you start doing something else with those images such as matching.
- **Keypoint angle** relates to the orientation of the feature that the keypoint represents. A keypoint is actually not a single pixel but a small region inside a feature (calling .pt.x and .pt.y just returns the center of the keypoint) so when changing it's orientation the pixels change their position from the perspective of the keypoint. Imagine you have a house with a door, roof etc. We extract some features of that house. Then we turn our camera upside down and take a new photo from the exact same position. If the feature extractor supports orientation, we should get (almost) the same features (ergo same keypoints) as in the picture we shot before that change in the orientation of our camera. If the feature extractor does **not** support orientation, we might loose most of our previously detected features and/or get new ones.

I recommend reading "Learning OpenCV". It is outdated in terms of OpenCV's API but the theory discussed there is really well explained.

Answer (score 4):

If someone came to this question wondering why does `keypoint.octave` have such a weird value (e.g. 16253184), it is because it actually carries the information on:

- the actual `octave` in the least significant byte of the `keypoint.octave` field
- the `layer` of that octave in the second least significant byte of the `keypoint.octave` field
- something else that gets packed into the third least significant byte by the SIFT keypoint detection, but doesn't get used by the SIFT descriptor

`keypoint.octave` gets unpacked into the variables `octave`, `layer`, and `scale` (`scale` is just 1/2^`octave`) with the method `unpackOctave` (see [OpenCV implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/xfeatures2d/src/sift.cpp)).

To get a visual understanding of variables `octave` and `layer`, this image might help:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Even though I know conceptual about the angle and octave, I wonder what the `float angle` mean, so I look in the source code of OpenCV2.3.1
in `sift.cpp`

```
inline KeyPoint featureToKeyPoint( const feature& feat )
{
    float size = (float)(feat.scl * SIFT::DescriptorParams::GET_DEFAULT_MAGNIFICATION() * 4); // 4==NBP
    float angle = (float)(feat.ori * a_180divPI);
    return KeyPoint( (float)feat.x, (float)feat.y, size, angle, feat.response, feat.feature_data->octv, feat.class_id );
}
```

ok, I get the angle definition, but what is `feat.ori` and `a_180divPI`
the latter is easy to find

```
const double a_180divPI = 180./CV_PI;
```

the former needs some effort, after look through several methods, I get

```
struct feature
{
    double x;                      /**< x coord */
    double y;                      /**< y coord */

    double scl;                    /**< scale of a Lowe-style feature */
    double ori;                    /**< orientation of a Lowe-style feature */

    ...
};
```

and the `feat.ori` is computed through several steps according to Lowe's Paper ( http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~lowe/papers/ijcv04.pdf ), including calculate ori_hist, smooth the histogram and add_good_ori_feature.
I am not 100% sure about the exactly meaning of the `ori`, but I strongly doubt that OpenCV have turned the `ori` to an proper arc representation, and the final result `angle` is the normal meaning angel range from -180 degree to 180 degree. The evidences are

```
1) ori = arctan2( dy, dx)
2) bin = cvRound( n * ( ori * CV_PI ) / PI_2 )
3) new_feat->ori = ( ( PI2 * bin ) / n ) - CV_PI;
```

hope help you

Comment: EDIT: I use OpenCV2.3.1. For `SIFT`, the angle is among **-180 to 180** degree. However, for `SURF`, the angle is among **0 to 360** degree. I don't know why. Also notice that, In the new document, it said _-1 if not applicable_ [link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#float angle)

Answer (score 1):

This may help with regards to the octave:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_pyramid

Basically, the image is blurred to varying degrees. The degree at which the feature is found is the 'octave' level of that feature.

Comment: To get an idea of what the octave is meant for you could say it encodes the "size" of the feature and its neighborhood needed to compute the descriptor.