# OpenCV how to calculate SIFT descriptor at a given pixel

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, sift, feature-descriptor

Hi guys I'm using opencv3 with the contrib. The question is I want to calculate a sift descriptor at a given pixel (not using the detected keypoints).

I'm trying to build a KeyPoint vector with given pixel. However, to create a KeyPoint I need to know the size information in addition to the pixel location.

```
KeyPoint (Point2f _pt, float _size, float _angle=-1, float _response=0, int _octave=0, int _class_id=-1)
```

Can anybody tell me what is the size in the constructor? Do I need the angle information in order to compute a sift descriptor? And how can I calculate them with poencv3.

Comment: SIFT computes the keypoints and desctriptors in a scale-space to make sure that differently scaled images will still produce the same keypoints and the same descriptors. So the scale of the keypoint will determine the size of the descriptor window around the keypoint. Similarly, the angle will make sure that rotated images will produce the same descriptors. So whether or not you have to choose a special size and angle depends on your special problem.

Comment: have a look at this, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561352/opencv-keypoint-information-about-angle-and-octave

Comment: Hi Micka the problem i'm facing now is that I have 3D models. I can take a snapshot of the model from one view and calculate the keypoints and descriptors for the image. After a rotation I can calculate a different set of keypoints and I can calculate the 3D position of the keypoints and these positions of the 3D points can be then transformed to UV coordinates in the first view. I want to do a brute force matching of these two set of keypoints to figure out the view invariance of the SIFT and Daisy descriptors of each model.

Comment: is there a reason why you don't want to use the detector?

Comment: I used the detector to find out the keypoints. I then transform the keypoints from the rotated image to the unrotated one and then I can make a BFmatching with the same image. The problem is do I need to computed new scales and orientations for the keypoints from the rotated image.

Comment: What I come up with is to build a DOG pyramid and find out the scale and octave with the extrema DOG. And I can then calculate the orientation for each pixel with the new scale and octave.

Comment: cant you just use the detector on the reference 3d model, too?

Comment: can you please add some sample images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@Utkarsh:** I agree to the fact that SIFT descriptor requires orientation and scale information of the Keypoint. Original paper by David G. Lowe (Distinctive Image Features from Scale-Invariant Keypoints) says, **"In order to achieve orientation invariance, the coordinates of the descriptor and the gradient orientations are rotated relative to the Keypoint orientation"**. while the **scale information is used for selecting the level of Gaussian blur for the image** during the calculation of descriptor.

However, the question is in this post was about calculating a descriptor for a given pixel. Note that given pixel location is not a SIFT Keypoint calculated using the desired procedure. So orientation and scale information is not available in this case. So the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25744075/how-to-find-descriptors-for-manualy-defined-landmarks-with-opencv/26030513#26030513) mentioned in previous answer calculate SIFT descriptor at a given pixel at default scale (i.e. 1) and default orientation (without rotating the gradient orientations of the neighbourhood).

**@Teng Long:** On a separate note, I think that the approach you are using to match Keypoints in the two images (original and rotated one) is somehow ambiguous. You should separately run the SIFT Keypoint detection on both the images and calculate their corresponding descriptors separately. Then, you can  use Brute Force matching to these two set of Keypoints.

The following code calculates SIFT Keypoints on an image and its 45 deg rotated version, and then compute the SIFT Keypoint descriptors using Brute Force matching.

```
# include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
# include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
# include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
# include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
# include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
# include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
# include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    Mat img_1, img_2;

    // Load image in grayscale format
    img_1 = imread( "scene.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );     

    // Rotate the input image without loosing the corners 
    Point center = Point(img_1.cols / 2, img_1.rows / 2);
    double angle = 45, scale = 1;
    Mat rot = getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, scale);
    Rect bbox = cv::RotatedRect(center, img_1.size(), angle).boundingRect();
    rot.at<double>(0,2) += bbox.width/2.0 - center.x;
    rot.at<double>(1,2) += bbox.height/2.0 - center.y;
    warpAffine(img_1, img_2, rot, bbox.size());

    // SIFT feature detector
    SiftFeatureDetector detector;
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

    detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 );
    detector.detect( img_2, keypoints_2 );

    // Calculate descriptors 
    SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;

    extractor.compute( img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
    extractor.compute( img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2 );

    // Matching descriptors using Brute Force
    BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2);
    std::vector<DMatch> matches;
    matcher.match(descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches);


    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between Keypoints
    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++ )
    { double dist = matches[i].distance;
      if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
      if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
    }   

    // Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 2*min_dist,
    //-- or a small arbitary value ( 0.02 ) in the event that min_dist is very
    //-- small)
    std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors_1.rows; i++ )
    { if( matches[i].distance <= max(2*min_dist, 0.02) )
      { good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
    }

    //-- Draw only "good" matches
    Mat img_matches;
    drawMatches( img_1, keypoints_1, img_2, keypoints_2,
               good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
               vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

    //-- Show detected matches
    imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
  }
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works great. While to make it run with OpenCV 3.2(contrib support),  I had to change both detector and extractor to Ptr<SIFT>: `Ptr<SIFT> ptrSift = SIFT::create(20, 3, 0.07, 15);` And then `ptrSift->detect(...), ptrSift->compute(...)`.